# Html entity problem in Struts2 <a href="#"></a> tag parameter

Tags: struts2, html-entities

Am passing some parameters through  in Struts2, and am getting below error when there is a HTML special Character in parameter value how can i over come this...?

A herf tage used:

```
<a href="ManufacturerProducts.action?manufId=<s:property value="manufId"/>&amp;mName=<s:property value="manufName"/>"><img src="<s:property value="manufLogo"/>" alt="<s:property value="manufName"/>" /></a>
```

Error:

```
12:21:46,034 WARN  [OgnlValueStack] Error setting expression ' A Manufacturing Co' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@4acc69'
ognl.ExpressionSyntaxException: Malformed OGNL expression:  A Manufacturing Co [ognl.ParseException: Encountered " <IDENT> "Manufacturing "" at line 1, column 4.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "," ...
    "=" ...
    "?" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "|" ...
    "bor" ...
    "^" ...
    "xor" ...
    "&" ...
    "band" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "neq" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<=" ...
    "lte" ...
    ">=" ...
    "gte" ...
    "in" ...
    "not" ...
    "<<" ...
    "shl" ...
    ">>" ...
    "shr" ...
    ">>>" ...
    "ushr" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "%" ...
    "instanceof" ...
    "." ...
    "(" ...
    "[" ...
    <DYNAMIC_SUBSCRIPT> ...
    "(" ...
    ]
    at ognl.Ognl.parseExpression(Ognl.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compile(OgnlUtil.java:225)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:209)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:160)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:288)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:199)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try**

```
<a href="ManufacturerProducts.action?manufId=<s:property value='manufId'/>&mName=<s:property value='manufName'/>">
    <img src="<s:property value='manufLogo'/>" alt="<s:property value='manufName'/>" />
</a>
```

**or**

```
<a href="ManufacturerProducts.action?manufId=${manufId}&mName=${manufName}">
    <img src="${manufLogo}" alt="${manufName}" />
</a>
```

**or**

```
<s:url id="urlId" action="ManufacturerProducts.action">
    <s:param name="manufId" value="manufId" />
    <s:param name="mName" value="manufName" />
</s:url>
<a href="${urlId}">
    <img src="${manufLogo}" alt="${manufName}" />
</a>
```

**or (better)**

```
<s:a action="ManufacturerProducts.action">
    <s:param name="manufId">${manufId}</s:param>
    <s:param name="mName">${manufName}</s:param>
    <img src="${manufLogo}" alt="${manufName}" />
</s:a>
```

**or (better)**

```
<s:a action="ManufacturerProducts.action">
    <s:param name="manufId" value="manufId" />
    <s:param name="mName" value="manufName" />
    <img src="${manufLogo}" alt="${manufName}" />
</s:a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more alternatove

```
<a href="javascript:loadvalue()">
    <img src="<s:property value='manufLogo'/>" alt="<s:property value='manufName'/>" />
</a>
```

javascript

```
function loadvalue(){
var param=encodeURI("manufId=<s:property value='manufId'/>&mName=<s:property value='manufName'/>");
window.location="ManufacturerProducts.action?"+param;
}
```